# How to convert this terminal syntax to PHP syntax for OpenSSL

Tags: php, macos, laravel, openssl, p12

I wish to covert a `.p12` file to `.pem` file. In Mac terminal, this command works,

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

I am using laravel 5.5

I tries using exec() but it outputs an empty file.

```
$p12path = storage_path($path).'/cert.p12';
$outputpem = storage_path($path).'/cert.pem';
exec('openssl pkcs12 -in ' . $p12path . ' -out '. $outputpem .' -nodes -clcerts');
```

Tried the above code but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function of `PHP` like this:

```
<?php
echo exec('openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts');
?>
```

> `exec()` is used to execute an external program/command.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer as correct and also upvote if it has resolved your issue.

Comment: oops.. its not working actually... the file is not there.. im using laravel.. could it be the file path?

Comment: @Naz - It sound slike the exact problem from [Convert P12 to PEM using PHP and OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5422205/608639).